# How can I use parameter to prevent sql injection when I must create SQL statement dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I have a partial likely code as below. I have to prevent SQL injection by using parameter like add code

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mystring", myString);
```

Is there possible to use it?

Because I have some dynamically parameters like "select XXX,XXX,....".

```
count = myStringLists.count;
sql.Append(" select");

foreach(string myString in myStringLists)
{    
    sql.Append(string.Format("{0} ", myString));

    if ((count--) > 1) sql.Append("\n ,"); else sql.Append("\n  ");
}
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: In single parameter,i will be 
"sql.Append("@myString");" instead of "sql.Append(string.Format("{0} ", myString));"

Comment: it's in ASP.NET 2.0 C#.

Comment: Parameters are used for VALUES in the WHERE clause or for VALUES in INSERT or UPDATE. They cannot be used to represent the column names or the field names. You'd better be sure that the values in your myStringLists don't come from user manually typed input

Comment: It may possible. Assume you have predefined parameter lists, use `StringBuilder` to build SQL query string with dynamic parameters and create `SqlCommand` which including those parameters (better to use a stored procedure). Depending on your operation (INSERT/UPDATE/SELECT), parameters should take proper place when doing `ExecuteNonQuery` or `ExecuteReader`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sp_executesql to execute dynamic sql

Please refer to [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)